# Search bar within Navbar using react-bulma-components not rendering

Tags: reactjs, bulma

I am trying to add a search bar within a navbar using react-bulma-components, but I get this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `TopNav`.

I don't get the error when I exclude the Navbar.Item containing a Field element. The following is my code:

```
    <Navbar>

      <Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Item renderAs="a" href="/">
          The Nomad
        </Navbar.Item>
        <Navbar.Burger>
        </Navbar.Burger>
      </Navbar.Brand>

      <Navbar.Item>
        <Field>
          <Control>
            <Input placeholder="Search" />
          </Control>
        </Field>
      </Navbar.Item>

    </Navbar>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out on my own. It turns out that Field, Control and Input are properties of the Form component. I had the following in my import statements (incorrect version):

```
import React from 'react';

import { Navbar } from 'react-bulma-components';
import { Field, Control, Input } from 'react-bulma-components';
```

What I should have had was this:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Navbar } from 'react-bulma-components';
import { Form } from 'react-bulma-components';
const { Field, Control, Input } = Form;
```